# Finding the focused child element within a parent element in Android

Tags: java, android

In Android, how do I find the focused child element within a parent element?

Comment: What are you trying to ask ?

Comment: That is really a joke. isnt it ?

Comment: @icbytes: Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: Hard to understand. That is really a joke.
Therfore one must downvote it ? Because of not understanding ? LOL.
I now will not be offensive and talk about intelligence.

I just want to know, what is hard to understand, if a person asks inside a DEVELOPERS forum about an ui control and a focus.
or if 

view.isfocused.

or

view.hasFocus

or

view.findFocus



Still unclear ???

Comment: a joke is imho that you didnt bother to Log.d the return value of View.isFocused(-

Comment: I use the button to get its parent ( a absolute layout ) , to ask, whether there is any element focused.
Please do not ask, why this, just take it.

Comment: @icbytes Asking an on-topic question doesn't make it a good question. I downvoted because you don't show any research effort.

Comment: What is unclear ? I really do not get You, all in here ?
All people today so bored, to spend their time with downvoting and commenting useless stuff ?

Comment: I think what he's asking is: how can one find out the focused child element within a parent element. Is that correct @icbytes?

Comment: WKS. Exactly.Thats it .

Answer (score 1):

A focused UI component is the one that is receiving user events. It is usually highlighted in some way e.g. a coloured border. If your reading this answer on a browser window, your browser window has some indication (e.g. colours/shadows) to indicate that this browser window is the UI component that is accepting events.

- When a button is clicked, it is focused.
- But if a button is focused, it does not mean that the button has been clicked.

Comment: I know all of this. I got a generic eventhandler for view events and i ask the ui elements (buttons f.e.) for their parent in order to get the focused view in it.

Comment: Have you tried using getCurrentFocus()? It returns the focused view in an Activity

Comment: let me try this. THX.

Comment: I cannot get Activity host = view.getContext();
It simply crashes. Will provide log soon.

Comment: Activity is a subclass of Context so you'd write `Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext()`. Can you please provide code so that we can see what exactly it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello again. Here is some code ( i use fragment activity ),to support api lower then 9. fragmentactivity returns null for this code 

    FragmentActivity fract = (FragmentActivity)     ((Fragment)this._MainInteraction).getActivity();
   
   View vf = fract.getCurrentFocus();

Answer (score 1):

As you can easily test by yourself, a button gains focus when you click it.

In the source code of `View.onTouchEvent()` you can see that the view gains focus on the first touch event, and on the second one Android calls your onClick listener :

```
// take focus if we don't have it already and we should in
// touch mode.
boolean focusTaken = false;
if (isFocusable() && isFocusableInTouchMode() && !isFocused()) {
    focusTaken = requestFocus();
}

if (!mHasPerformedLongPress) {
    // This is a tap, so remove the longpress check
    removeLongPressCallback();

    // Only perform take click actions if we were in the pressed state
    if (!focusTaken) {
        // Perform click
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have added, that my button is inherited from button and therefore ( or why ever )  is not focusable.
After setting it focusable I finally get it